# Sieve of Eratosthenes infinite list

Tags: haskell, recursion, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Hello i have to implement a function for sieve of Eratosthenes.

I already have a function

```
removep p l
```

that removes elements of `l` that match the predicate `p` and a function

```
nats
```

that returns an infinite list of naturals numbers, and i am supposed to use both in my solution.

Now, i do understand how the sieve itself works but it seems i am having problems implementing this.

I am doing something like this:

```
sieve = (drop 1 nats)
 where
   sieve (h:t) = h : (removep (\x -> (mod x p) == 0) t) : sieve
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any help?
Also note that this is an assignment so if possible do not give away the exact solution. Id rather get an idea of what i am doing wrong and how i need to change it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refreshing to see someone just asking for a point in the right direction instead of for someone else to do all the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that you get the list of `nats` as a starting point for sieve. Then you recursively apply your `removep` function with your predicate to all but the first elements.

You are close, but i think your problem lies in the notation (see Bakuriu's answer)
I won't give you the answer but i will give you a hint:

```
sieve = s (drop 1 nats)
  where
    -- Recursive definition of s here
    -- s (h:t) = ???
```

I hope i didn't give away too much to make it trivial. Good luck.

**PS**: As Bakuriu mentioned, this is really not a true sieve. For more info on the matter, take a look [**here**](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. You want to define a `sieve` list that should be the list of primes, but in the `where` you *shadow* the name `sieve` with a function. Inside this definition you use `sieve` as a list, but here it actually references the function and thus you get a typeerror.

   You want to apply a function to `drop 1 nats` to obtain the list of primes.
2. In `mod x p` it should be `mod x h` since `h` is the prime you are considering there.
3. You are defining `sieve (h:t) = h:removep ... :_`  But here you are creating a list where the first element is `h`, a number, the second element is `removep ...`, which is a list, and then the remaining elements are taken by `sieve` (which is incorrect as already said.
4. Nitpicking: technically this is not the sieve of eratosthenes because in the algorithm of the sieve you *never* actually use `mod` to check for divisibility.

Comment: Thanks for the points. About (2), its a typo. The idea was to apply `removep` with arguments `(\x -> (mod x h) == 0) `and `t` so that whatever is divisible by the head of the list gets removed.