# Function for infinite list excluding multiples of three

Tags: list, haskell

This question is related to my previous question [Removing items from a list if a predicate holds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785585/removing-items-from-a-list-if-a-predicate-holds-haskell/34785741#34785741) .

I am struggling with outputting an infinite list which does not contain any multiple of three.
For that I have these few functions till now:

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete deleted xs = [ x | x <- xs, x /= deleted ]

removeif ::(a -> Bool)->[a]->[a]
removeif func [] = []
removeif func (h:t)= if func h then delete h (h:t) else removeif func t

nothreefolds :: [Integer]
nothreefolds = removeif (x `mod` 3 == 0) [1..]
```

But the problem is that I am missing some syntax knowledge and I want to tell `removeif` to remove the elements from natural numbers if they are multiple of 3.

If you can please help me to the right direction, I will be thoroughly grateful.

Comment: Note: I believe you are doing some exercises/assignments. Just *yesterday* questions similar to yours were asked about finding prime numbers ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34770836/510937)). Also: do *not* add the `(Haskell)` to the title. A title should be a sentence not something with some tags added to it. We already have tags on question, there is no need to add them to the title too.

Comment: Note: You've asked six questions in five days. If you post two questions per day, you will [hit the limit on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). However, I think you would be better off with some kind of mentoring, at least while you're still dabbling with Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`removeif` wants a *function* as first argument. But `` x `mod` 3 == 0 `` is not a function. It's an expression that references a non-existing name `x`.

You want to use a *lambda abstraction*: `` \x -> x `mod` 3 == 0 ``.
The `\x ->` part says that this is a function with one parameter called `x`.
The result is given by the following expression.

Alternatively you could simply use sections and function composition: `` (== 0) . (`mod` 3) ``.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help ,only now I get it yohoooo :)

Comment: Additionally, GHC complained that it couldn't find an `Eq` instance for the `delete` function. As suggested by compiler, adding typeclass context `Eq a =>` to the `removeif` function solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Using composition :

```
 removeThreeMultiple =  filter ( (/= 0) . (`mod` 3))
```

Example:

```
 Prelude>  removeThreeMultiple  [1,2,3,4,9,0]
 [1,2,4]
```

Make it simple, try to write correctly the intermediate function that checks if a number is a mutliple of three or not. Then use it to clean your list.

Comment: Thank you, I am a new learner of Haskell, I did not know that its also possible this way, Thanks!!!! :)